Merge a gt table with a table created with gtsummary
I have created a gtsummary table based on a dataset (reference this StackOverflow Q&A)
Here is the data and table from this example:
Load required libraries
library(dplyr) library(tidyr) library(gtsummary) library(gt)

Create a sample dataframe
mydf <- data.frame(
  species = c("Species1", "Species1", "Species1", "Species2", "Species2", "Species2", "Species3", "Species3"),
  season = c("Spring", "Spring", "Summer", "Spring", "Spring", "Summer", "Spring", "Summer"),
  region = c("Region1", "Region2", "Region1", "Region2", "Region1", "Region1", "Region1", "Region1")
)

Create a summary table by season and for each species, subdivide by region
tbl <- 
  tbl_strata(
    data = mydf,
    strata = species,
    \(df_subset) {
      tbl_summary(
        data = df_subset,
        by = season,
        missing = "no",
        label = list(region = "Region", season = "Season")
      ) |> 
        modify_table_body(
          ~.x %>% mutate(across(all_stat_cols(),~gsub("^0.*", "-", .)))
        ) |> 
        remove_row_type(type = "header") |> 
        modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**")
    },
    .combine_with = "tbl_stack"
  )

The table looks like this:

Now, I need to merge data from a dataframe (fancyData) into this Table.
The fancy data has a fancy number of each species/region/season combination.
species <- c("Species1", "Species2")
seasons <- c("Summer", "Spring")
region <- c("Region1", "Region2", "Region3")
mydf2 <- expand.grid(Species = species, Season = seasons, Region = region)
mydf2$fancyData <- sample(1:485, 12, replace = FALSE)

I can create a similarly formatted table (similar to mydf, above) using gt package:
tbl2 <- mydf2 %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Season", values_from = "fancyData")%>%
  gt(
    groupname_col = "Species", 
    rowname_col = "Site"
  )
tbl2

This table has the same format

I would like this fancyData inserted into the table in a way that makes sense
(see faked example below):

I've been unable to create the table in this format with add_stat, tbl_merge.

You could attempt using dplyr::bind_cols() between both datasets.

I found a work-around to merge these two tables that involves deconstructing the two formatted tables and then merging them. This is not my favorite-- but it did work.
First, load libraries
library(dplyr) library(tidyr) library(gtsummary) library(gt) library(zoo)

Create DataSet
    mydf <- data.frame(
species = c("Species1", "Species1", "Species1", "Species2", "Species2", "Species2", "Species3", "Species3"),
season = c("Spring", "Spring", "Summer", "Spring", "Spring", "Summer", "Spring", "Summer"),
region = c("Region1", "Region2", "Region1", "Region2", "Region1", "Region1", "Region1", "Region1")
)

Create Table #1 with Summary Table (gtSummary)
tbl <- 
  tbl_strata(
    data = mydf,
    strata = species,
    \(df_subset) {
      tbl_summary(
        data = df_subset,
        by = season,
        missing = "no",
        label = list(region = "Region", season = "Season")
      ) |> 
        modify_table_body(
          ~.x %>% mutate(across(all_stat_cols(),~gsub("^0.*", "-", .)))
        ) |> 
        remove_row_type(type = "header") |>
        modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**")
    },
    .combine_with = "tbl_stack"
  )
tbl

Create Table #2 with Fancy Data
Create Dataset with Fancy Data
species <- c("Species1", "Species2", "Species3")
seasons <- c("Spring", "Summer")
region <- c("Region1", "Region2")
        
mydf2 <- expand.grid(Species = species, Season = seasons, Region = region)
mydf2$fancyData <- sample(1:485, 12, replace = FALSE)
mydf2

Create Table#2 with gt
tbl2 <- mydf2 %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Season", values_from = "fancyData")%>%
  gt(
    groupname_col = "Species", 
    rowname_col = "Site",
  )

tbl2

To create the merged table, extract body of Table#2 and save Table#1 as tibble, merge, and create final table (includes addition of zoo package).
test2 <- extract_body(tbl2)  
colnames(test2) <-c("Species", "Region", "Spring-DP", "Summer-DP")

test1 <-  as_tibble(tbl) 
colnames (test1) <- (c("Species", "Region", "Spring-Sum", "Summer-Sum"))
test1$Species <- na.locf(test1$Species, na.rm = TRUE, fromLast = FALSE)

#merge Tables by Columns
TestTable <- merge(test1, test2, all = TRUE)
TestTable[is.na(TestTable)] <- 0
TestTable <- TestTable[,c(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6)]

FinalTable <- TestTable %>%
  gt(
  groupname_col = "Species", 
  rowname_col = "Site",
)%>%
  tab_spanner(
    label = "Spring", 
    columns = c(`Spring-DP`, `Spring-Sum`)
  )%>%
  tab_spanner(
    label = "Summer", 
    columns = c(`Summer-DP`, `Summer-Sum`)
  ) %>%
  tab_style(
    style = list(cell_fill(color = "#DBE5F1")),
    locations = list(cells_column_labels(), cells_column_spanners())
  ) %>%
  tab_style(
    cell_text(weight = "bold"), locations = list(cells_row_groups(), 
                                                 cells_column_labels(), cells_column_spanners())
  ) %>%
  cols_label(
    "Spring-DP" ~ "Daily Prob",
    "Spring-Sum" ~ "Sum (%)",
    "Summer-DP" ~ "Daily Prob",
    "Summer-Sum" ~ "Sum (%)"
  )
FinalTable

The final table looks like this:

